# How to use internal speaker to play sound while a 3.5mm jack plugged to record sound using an external microphone

Tags: android, audio-recording, speaker

I'm now programming an app to give vocal feedback through internal speaker while user performing some exercises.

Now I want to add a function to record the user's heartbeat and breathe through a stethoscope plugged in the phone by a 3.5mm jack. The problem is that when I plug in the jack, the speaker won't play any sound because the phone think that earpieces were connected and the sound will be played through them.

What I want to achieve is to record the sound by a stethoscope plugged in the phone while play sound through internal speaker.

Basically I use two ways to play sound, MediaPlayer and TextToSpeech.

I searched on the internet, found these articles:

[Forcing sound output through speaker in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917184/forcing-sound-output-through-speaker-in-android)

[want to play TTS on Bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518452/want-to-play-tts-on-bluetooth-headset)

What they told me to do is to add permission MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS to manifest

declare variables:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer; 
AudioManager mAudioManager;
HashMap<String, String> mHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

in OnCreate method：

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ding);
mHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
...
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, mHashAlarm);
```

But neither of them works.

Does anyone know how to achieve this function? Any ideas would be a lot of help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you perhaps found a solution in the while? I'd love to achieve something similar. Thank you

Comment: @Anal Unfortunately I still didn't find any solution. At last I used an additional phone to record sound. And since then my project is finished and I didn't dig it further.

Answer (score -1):

Simply purchase a audio splitter...after that u get two ports plug your external  mic on one and plug any speaker on another ....